# An identity involves Hilbert matrix

Tags: matrices

While thinking this [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242605/proof-that-e-n-int-01-left-ln-t-p-nt-right-mathrmdt-1-n12),I found an identity:
$b_n^TH_n^{-1}b_n+\frac{1}{n^2}=2$,where $b_n=(\frac{1}{1^2} \frac{1}{2^2} ... \frac{1}{n^2})^T$,and $H_n$ is the n-th [Hilbert matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix).However,I cannot prove it directly.Does anybody give me some hints to prove this identity?